# What do the spirit, vitality, etc. stats affect?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

What do the attribute values such as "Spirit" and "Vitality" do in FF7?  I know one of these helps to reduce damage, but an explanation of what each category does would be helpful for early-game strategies (I'm replaying!).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Spirit affects magic defense.  Having more spirit lowers incoming magic attack damage.

One note from the [wiki](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Spirit_%28Stat%29):

> The player's overall Magic Defense was intended to be a sum of the character's Spirit stat and the MDef value of their armor, but due to a bug in the coding, the MDef value is not used and Spirit alone determines the character's Magic Defense.

Vitality affects physical defense.  High vitality lowers damage from physical attacks.

**EDIT:** There's a full guide here (Thanks for the wiki link):

http://faqs.ign.com/articles/452/452504p1.html

Pasted relevant information:

```
?================?================?==========================?===============?
| Stat Name      | Purpose        | How Stat is Increased    | Stat Maximum  |
?================?================?==========================?===============?
| Strength       | Attack Power   | Power Sources            |       255 (+) |
|                |                | Gaining Levels           |               |
?----------------+----------------+--------------------------+---------------?
| Dexterity      | Speed (ATB)    | Speed Sources            |       255 (+) |
|                |                | Gaining Levels           |               |
?----------------+----------------+--------------------------+---------------?
| Vitality       | Attack Defense | Guard Sources            |       255 (+) |
|                |                | Gaining Levels           |               |
?----------------+----------------+--------------------------+---------------?
| Magic          | Magic Power    | Magic Sources            |       255 (+) |
|                |                | Gaining Levels           |               |
?----------------+----------------+--------------------------+---------------?
| Spirit         | Magic Defense  | Mind Sources             |       255 (+) |
|                |                | Gaining Levels           |               |
?----------------+----------------+--------------------------+---------------?
| Luck           | Critical Hits  | Luck Sources             |       255 (+) |
|                |                | Gaining Levels           |               |
?----------------+----------------+--------------------------+---------------?
```

Comment: the linked wiki now states that "the bug was finally fixed for the 2012 PC re-release."

Answer (score 7):

I found another guide that goes into much more detail for each stat, from [this](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197341-final-fantasy-vii/faqs/45703) guide:

> ### HP (Hit Points):
>
> HP is a character's life. When depleted, the character will be KO'd in
>   battle. When the HP of all characters in your party is depleted, it
>   will be game over. HP is increased when a character levels up.
>
> ### MP (Magic Points):
>
> MP is used to cast Magic. Every spell requires a certain amount of MP
>   to be cast. The points are deducted after the casting. When you have
>   insufficient MP to cast a certain spell, you simply can't it.
>
> ### Strength (Str):
>
> Strength is used to power up a character's physical attacks. The
>   higher your Str, the higher damage you will do with physical attacks.
>
> ### Vitality (Vit):
>
> Vitality is used to power up a character's defense against physical
>   attacks. The higher your Vit, the less damage you'll receive from
>   enemy attacks that fall under physical attacks.
>
> ### Magic (Mag):
>
> Magic is used to power up the magic that a character can use. This
>   includes summons as well as regular magic and enemy skills. The higher
>   your Mag, the higher damage you'll hit with magic.
>
> ### Spirit (Spr):
>
> Spirit is used to power up a character's defense against magical
>   attacks. The higher your Spr, the less damage you'll take from enemy
>   attacks that fall under magical attacks. This is an important stat,
>   because there is a bug in the game that causes the magical defense
>   that armor gives not to be taken in account. This means your magic
>   defense is always just your Spirit stat.
>
> ### Dexterity (Dex):
>
> Dexterity is basically the speed of your characters, and it determines
>   how fast their bars will fill up. Dexterity is ALSO an important part
>   of a characters evasion against physical attacks. Thus, it's part of
>   Defense% (= Physical Evasion). The higher your Dex, the faster your
>   character will be, and the more physical attacks they will evade.
>
> ### Luck (Lck):
>
> Luck increases the chance to perform a critical hit with physical
>   attacks. It ALSO increases the chance to get a 'lucky evade' in which
>   case you will evade physical attacks. The higher your Lck, the more
>   critical hits you will perform, and the more attacks you will evade.
>   The chance formula for getting a lucky evade is like this: % =
>   [Luck/4]. Max Luck (255) would give you a 63% chance because [] means
>   you round down.